# Meaning of the line marker with 'blue ball' when stepping through code in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can anyone tell me what this icon (with the blue ball) means, as opposed to the normal step-through marker without the ball?

[image: VS icon with blue ball]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other software installed (code helpers, etc)? I have not seen the blue ball, but there could be a debugging plug-in or other tool that adds the blue balls. I know it is not an advanced breakpoint (see: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/02/14/visual-studio-2008-debugging-tricks-ndash-advanced-breakpoints.aspx)

Comment: Nope, no code-helpers or plugins.  I had the evaluation version of resharper installed, but that's gone now.